# Power BI Reports template for DBA's

Tags: sql, powerbi

Sorry If I am asking a question that has been asked before, however I couldn't really find an answer.

Looking to see if anyone has any recommendations for some good Power BI templates for monitoring SQL servers, looking for something that includes Disk Usage/Utilisation stats (used space/free space, drive, label etc).

Have looked around here as well as the good ol' internet, but I can only seem to find one that look at the actual databases, in terms of size of tables and associated information.

Want to get into PBI and thought this would be something that lots of people would be doing, but just cannot seem to find anything.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brent Ozar's sp_BlitzFirst tool has Power BI Report to show the collected data. See [First Responder Kit Power BI Dashboard](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/first-responder-kit-power-bi-dashboard/).

To use it, you must install and configure sp_BlitzFirst to collect data, by running a SQL Server Agent job every lets say 15 minutes, like this:

```
EXEC sp_BlitzFirst 
  @OutputDatabaseName = 'DBAtools', 
  @OutputSchemaName = 'dbo', 
  @OutputTableName = 'BlitzFirst',
  @OutputTableNameFileStats = 'BlitzFirst_FileStats',
  @OutputTableNamePerfmonStats = 'BlitzFirst_PerfmonStats',
  @OutputTableNameWaitStats = 'BlitzFirst_WaitStats',
  @OutputTableNameBlitzCache = 'BlitzCache';
```

Of course, you can change `OutputDatabaseName`. Then point the First Responder Kit Power BI file at your SQL Server and database, where the data is stored.

Comment: Thanks for this, have had a good look at this, think the only thing that is missing is the server drive space, so may try and add this myself, or may need to look elsewhere.